# Errol Morris on Aspect Ratios

Tags: film-techniques, documentary, aspect-ratio

In a recorded interview on his film *Standard Operating Procedure*, Errol Morris declares that

> [the film] is about photographs, how they reveal and conceal at the same time.

(This could be a paraphrase; unfortunately I seem to not have noted which interview this is but most likely it's on Youtube.)

It is reasonable that Morris has thought about this "simultaneous revaling and concealing" when it comes to his own films as well. My question is something more specific: What is Morris' approach to aspect ratios in his films? Is it known that he uses aspect ratios as a cinematic tool? An answer may take the advertisements he directed into account as well.

(Note that the relation between the film and aspect ratios is due to that part of the film where Morris focuses on the technical details about the photographs and the camera that was used to take the photographs.)

Comment: This sounds like you want us to do research for you and write some kind of thesis for you. This is not what this site is for.

Comment: @BCdotWEB This site is very much *all* about doing other's research for them. The only question is, would the result have the size of an actual thesis or is it condensable into a reasonably sized answer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson There is a difference between a google search and "please analyze this director's entire body of work". IMHO "What is Morris' approach to aspect ratios in his films?" is far too broad a question, especially considering he's got 30-something director credits in IMDb.

Comment: @BCdotWEB If you think it's too broad, that is a valid point of view indeed. I would, however, eschew the emphasis on research and the idea that we won't do people's leg work for them, because that is *all* we do. If the question is too broad, then it is too broad, but *not* because it would be too much work for us to analyze the director's work (afterall someone might already have done it anyway). If you can't or don't want to do the work for answering a question, you don't have to. If you think the question is too broad to be answered reasonably, then *that* is the fault of the question.

Comment: @BCdotWEB To elaborate further on your example, questions that can *not* be answered with a Google search are the ones that actually make the internet a better place, as it turns this site *into* the search result. The idea that everyone has to be able to answer a question with a Google search will have answers end up with nothing but quote blocks. Not everyone needs to be able to answer every question easily. As said, the question might be too broad, I'm not yet clear on that. But that is because the answer won't fit into the SE format, not because the average joe can't answer it in 5 minutes